# ActionbarSherlock - crashing with a list_navigation error about layout_height attribute

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have this implementation of the list_navigation of ActionbarSherlock:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

And this is my xml for list_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/list_navigation_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the array of items for the navigation:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="locations">
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>Learn</item>
        <item>Services</item>
        <item>Next Steps</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And the dropdown renders. The crash happens when I choose one of the items. Here is the crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #20: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5319)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5271)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.java:4471)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:569)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:565)
        at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:513)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:739)
        at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:453)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Would anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your layout for list items?

Comment: @Karakuri I just added the array with the list of items to the original question.

Comment: No, i was asking for the layout of the list items/spinner content. `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item` and `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item`

Comment: @Karakuri ah that is a part of what I am confused about. Where do I need to have these? I wasn't sure what the example code was referring to when it referenced those.

Comment: Do you have much Android programming experience? These are constants that are generated at compile time and are used to reference resources in your `/res` folders from java. `R.layout.foo` should match a file `/res/layout/foo.xml`. If this is not familiar to you, go through the docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html

Comment: @Karakuri yeah I know those things :) Just getting used to new code and confused over some parts of it. Largely, I am confused because I do not see the R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item and R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item in the code examples I am working from.

Comment: They appear to be in the ActionBarSherlock library project. The `sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item` layout references a theme attribute for the `layout_height` attribute. Is your app's theme extending one of the Sherlock themes? If not, then this theme attribute is probably not defined for your theme.

Comment: @Karakuri do you mean in my manifest, I need to specify that I am extending the ActionbarSherlock theme? I remember reading something like that in the docs.

Comment: You can use one directly like that, but most people make their own in `styles/xml` that extends one of Sherlock's and use that

Comment: @Karakuri Would you be able to post a sample of how it would look? I am a bit confused and not finding it in the ActionbarSherlock samples. Sorry if this is too basic. I am new to the ActionbarSherlock world.

Comment: I think the error appears after I update ABS support v4 to the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is similar to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/aODtoH2aS-s). It seems the root cause still hasn't been found, but you can solve it by either calling

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light)
```

in your your activity onCreate() method. Alternatively, you can modify the `sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` in folder `actionbarsherlock\res\layout-v14` the line

```
android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

Comment: so do you think it is this line that is causing the problem?  <include android:id="+id/header"
         layout="layout/header"/>

Comment: That was my understanding of your answer. Or did I misunderstand it. I think I am confused into which snippet of xml I am supposed to place the layout_height element

Comment: I don't think I ever pointed to that line as the cause of the problem. As mentioned, I think no one has definitive root cause yet. Does any of the suggestions above help?

Comment: ah yeah I misunderstood where to make the edit at first. Plus Dinesh's answer pointed to that line.  Let me mess with it a little bit and see what happens. I'll comment back here in a little bit.

Comment: Sure. If you have any concrete solution I think it is better to contribute to the link I included in the post ;)

Comment: so this actually worked setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light) but I don't quite understand why :) Would you be able to explain why? LOL Thanks!

Comment: You are right man..   Thanks I would have wasted my time unless I get this thread..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your theme extends one of the ones in the ActionBarSherlock library.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <!-- override theme attributes for your app here -->
</style>
```

You can extend `Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, or `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: aaaah ok..I am beginning to understand. What i had before was this: <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> so I will try to change it to Theme.Sherlock and see what happens :)

Comment: I just did this and got the same crash <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">

Comment: Also using Theme.Sherlock.Light causes the crash :(

Answer (score 0):

I think in your activity_main.xml line 20 you forgot to give the layout_height attribute.